# Keep words starting with character/letter in Pandas | Python

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I'm not sure how to do this in a dataframe context

I have the table below here with text information

```
TEXT                                       | 
-------------------------------------------|
"Get some new #turbo #stacks today!"       |
"Is it one or three? #phone"               |
"Mayhaps it be three afterall..."          |
"So many new issues with phone... #iphone" |
```

And I want to edit it down to where only the words with a '#' symbol are kept, like in the result below.

```
TEXT             | 
-----------------|
"#turbo #stacks" |
"#phone"         |
""               |
"#iphone"        |
```

In some cases, I'd also like to know if it's possible to eliminate the rows that are empty by checking for NaN as true or if you run a different kind of condition to get this result:

```
TEXT             | 
-----------------|
"#turbo #stacks" |
"#phone"         |
"#iphone"        |
```

Python 2.7 and pandas for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using regex and `extractall`:

```
df.TEXT.str.extractall('(#\w+)').groupby(level=0)[0].apply(' '.join)
```

Output:

```
0    #turbo #stacks
1            #phone
3           #iphone
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Comment: `df.TEXT.str.extractall('(#\w+)').sum(level=0)`  :-)

Comment: would you mind add this step `reindex`? `df.TEXT.str.extractall('(#\w+)').groupby(level=0)[0].apply(' '.join).reindex(df.index,fill_value='')`

Comment: Yep, this solution works. Wen's solution is also suitable for this problem. EDIT: Note to readers: This solution also eliminates any rows without '#' words at the exact same time.